# upgrade from Redmine 1.3.2 to Redmine 2.2.2 on Ubuntu 12.04.1 [LTS]

Tags: ubuntu, upgrade, redmine

I had installed Redmine 1.3.2 from official repository on Ubuntu 12.04.1 (LTS).
Redmine 1.3.2 worked via nginx and thin.

Then I decided to upgrade it to Redmine 2.2.2 (latest for now).

I run the following commands:

```
add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/redmine 
apt-get update 
apt-get install redmine redmine-mysql
```

no errors, everything was removed and installed.

then i did

```
rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=production
rake generate_secret_token
```

from redmine root folder `/usr/share/redmine` in my case

And what I have is only one small problem: Redmine has wrong url to JS and CSS files, all other content is visible.

Now the url looks like:

```
https://domain/themes/highrise_tabs/stylesheets/application.css?1326492267
```

and nginx returns 404 naturally, because the real address has to be

```
https://domain/redmine/themes/highrise_tabs/stylesheets/application.css?1326492267
```

I've found the solution on the official site

```
Redmine::Utils::relative_url_root = "/redmine"
```

Finally i got what I wanted and only one thing disappointed me, perfomance became worse. Everyone told that new redmine much faster... but i can't confirm the same. From my point it's slower :(

Maybe someone knows what I should do to make it faster?

Answer (score 0):

Using [Phusion Passenger 5](https://www.phusionpassenger.com/) gives a huge boost for mine. Also check [gzip & mimified .js and .css files](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30490597/542730) to speed up resource loading time.

This required to install Nginx + Passenger + PageSpeed in once. You can read [my post](http://scyu.logdown.com/posts/93686-install-nginx-with-passenger-ngx-pagespeed-and-spdy) for installation detail.